# WSS - WSRP producer

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, wsrp

I am trying to use the WSRP producer with WSS. Is this possible or do I need MOSS? How can i pass the user credentials to SharePoint Server?

Please see my log http://pastebin.com/m501eef46.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested this with WSS, so you do not need MOSS.

Sending creditials depends on what your server side settings are.

Comment: I am trying to consume webparts with Liferay Portal. I have two servers, same intranet, Server 1 with OS Windows Server 2008, SQL Server 2008, WSS, IIS 7, SharePoint Producer Web Service version 1.0
, and Server 2 with OS CentOS 5, Liferay 5.2.3 with Tomcat 6, and WSRP consumer. Please could you send me an example showing me how can I send credentials. For more help watch this forum http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WSRPToolkit/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=1612 Thank you very much for your help.